# Vue component doesn't detect data changes commited by parent mounted()

Tags: vue.js

I have this simple app that keeps changing the background color for a box via a `setInterval`on the `mounted()` life-cycle hook on the main instance :

**what is the issue ?**

If you press the button(click me)...the `color` property **will** change and the child component will **detect** that change.

But when the color is changed dynamically (via `setInterval`) you can see on the console that the color **is changing** but the component doesn't detect that change (you can see that on the console also).

**what i want to know ?**

simply ... why the component doesn't detect such mutations (dynamic mutations) while it detects the other manual mutations (via events...etc) ?

**here is a snippet representing my app :**

```js
Vue.component('coloredComp', {
  props: ['color'],
  watch: {
    color() {
      console.log('changed')
    }
  },
  template: "<div id='box' :style='{backgroundColor : color}'></div>"
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      let colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
      let i = 0;
      var int = setInterval(function() {
        this.color = colors[i];
        console.log('the new color is : ' + window.color)
        i++;
        i == colors.length ? i=0 : '';
      }, 2000)
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="color = 'blue'">click me</button>
  <colored-comp :color="color"></colored-comp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `setInterval(fn` `this` is undefined/not bound

```
var int = setInterval(function() {
  this.color = colors[i];           // < -- here this is undefined
  console.log('the new color is : ' + this.color)
  i++;
  i == colors.length ? i=0 : '';
}, 2000)
```

solution:

either

- use `() => {}` syntax (which binds `this` implicitly)
- or bind manually `setInterval( (function() { ... }).bind(this) )`
- or close over it `const that = this; setInterval( (function() { that.... })`

Comment: So i wasn't mutating this value `vm.$data.color` but i was mutating the global variable `window.color` instead ...Thank you

Comment: @Dadboz: correct, I occasionally use `console.log(this, this.color)` or similar to make sure `this` it what one expects `this` to be